# Apache Beam, Dataflow: retrying _gcs_file_copy because we caught exception: socket.timeout

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to run a Dataflow job that used to rune fine but now I get a timeout exception.

The command that I run:

```
python -m dataflow --input_topic projects/xxx/subscriptions/yyy --events_table_name events --postgres_user postgres --postgres_password xxx --postgres_db test-db --postgres_host xx.xx.xx.xx --region us-central1 --temp_location gs://temp_test_356/tmp/ --project xxx --runner DataflowRunner --setup_file ./setup.py
```

The exception:

```
WARNING:root:Make sure that locally built Python SDK docker image has Python 3.8 interpreter.
WARNING:apache_beam.utils.retry:Retry with exponential backoff: waiting for 4.58774193007135 seconds before retrying _gcs_file_copy because we caught exception: socket.timeout: The write operation timed out
 Traceback for above exception (most recent call last):
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/utils/retry.py", line 253, in wrapper
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 565, in _gcs_file_copy
    self.stage_file(to_folder, to_name, f, total_size=total_size)
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/runners/dataflow/internal/apiclient.py", line 641, in stage_file
    response = self._storage_client.objects.Insert(request, upload=upload)
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apache_beam/io/gcp/internal/clients/storage/storage_v1_client.py", line 1152, in Insert
    return self._RunMethod(
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apitools/base/py/base_api.py", line 728, in _RunMethod
    http_response = http_wrapper.MakeRequest(
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 348, in MakeRequest
    return _MakeRequestNoRetry(
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/apitools/base/py/http_wrapper.py", line 397, in _MakeRequestNoRetry
    info, content = http.request(
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 173, in new_request
    resp, content = request(orig_request_method, uri, method, body,
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 280, in request
    return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 173, in new_request
    resp, content = request(orig_request_method, uri, method, body,
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/oauth2client/transport.py", line 280, in request
    return http_callable(uri, method=method, body=body, headers=headers,
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1708, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1424, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/home/schnitzel/Visual Code Projects/python_scripts/QuestRewardConsumer/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1347, in _conn_request
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1256, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1302, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1251, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 1050, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/http/client.py", line 972, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1204, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/ssl.py", line 1173, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
```

Like I said, this job used to run (it still runs fine local). I drained the previous job and then wanted to start it again but without success. I've spent countless hours on this issue. The last time that I had this problem I had to create a new virtual machine just to get my jobs running but now I want to get to the bottom of this. Things that I've tried:

- Set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS with service account that is Owner.
- Configure gcloud. Remove gcloud.
- Use neither of above two and use the automatic login mechanism when you run the script.
- Change machine type.
- Change job name.
- Change region.
- Use python, use python3.